# Do restlet contains XACML?

Tags: restlet, xacml

Is XACML supported by Restlet? If so, how is it used?

Answer (score 0):

XACML is not currently supported by Restlet.

There is an [open issue](http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=716) on the matter, but it hasn't been touched in 4 years. It's currently considered a [low priority](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/g1/212-restlet.html) enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not particularly need support from Restlet itself. You can use Java XACML PEP SDKs to write the enforcement point that will filter within the Restlet apps.

Have a look at WSO2 (open source) or Axiomatics (vendor). They are the main XACML 3.0 implementations and they both have Java SDKs to implement your own PEPs including support for Restlet.